# Perl regex matching is not working in my code

Tags: perl, design-patterns

I have a very large file that contains lines like below:

```
NO BIOMETRICS: 2000 ARIZONA/PHOENIX[1] {ARIZONA_PHOENIX_1_} AI
NO BIOMETRICS: 2090 ARIZONA/PHOENIX[2] {ARIZONA_PHOENIX_2_INTER} AB
NO BIOMETRICS: 900 TEXAS/DALLAS__1 {TEXAS_DALLAS_1_} NOCRIMINALHIST
NO BIOMETRICS: 0002 ALABAMA/HUNTSVILLE {ALABAMA/HUNTSVILLE} STATEPENITENTIARY
```

I only want to print only when my regular expression does not match  `ARIZONA`

I am using the following code to print all cases where there is no  `ARIZONA`  in the rows I am processing

```
if($line =~ /(?!ARIZONA)/) {
 print $line,"\n";
}
```

but that does not seem to work and it still prints the rows that have  `ARIZONA`  in them.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just do `if ( $line !~ /ARIZONA/ ) `

Answer (score 6):

`(?!ARIZONA)` matches if the current position isn't followed by `ARIZONA`, so `/(?!ARIZONA)/` (effectively `/\A(?s:.*?)(?!ARIZONA)/`) matches if any position isn't followed by `ARIZONA`. All strings match since the end of the string will never be followed by `ARIZONA`.

You need to check that all positions aren't followed by `ARIZONA`. You were going for

```
if ($line =~ /^(?:(?!ARIZONA).)*\z/s) {
```

You want

```
if ($line !~ /ARIZONA/) {
```

Comment: Your clarification is better :-)